# JSP / HTML UI Design

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat

We have some JSP code to run in our pages.

There is a UI designer who will constantly update the UI but does not have Tomcat server. We prefer he doesn't because he isn't a programmer.

However, it is getting annoying to have to cut and paste the JSP related code each time he updates the UI.

Is there anyway to handle this issue?  We prefer to keep the same files, but still have it so he can see his UI work without worrying about the JSP and when he checks in the new files, we don't have to cut and paste our JSP related code.

One example of such code, is that there are certain navigation menu items which are displayed depending on the user.

We are using Tomcat authentication.  We could I suppose use AJAX to obtain the user information, but is that less secure?  Everything else in the application is AJAX.

Comment: Is the question about pushing design changes or about the security of AJAX in logins?

Comment: If hes workign on the frontend he needs to get his feet wet setting up and maintaining a local envrionment and learning a bit of JSP/JSTL if thats what hes working with at the moment. Its going to be better for him (and for you guys) in the long run.

Comment: Both of you could you includes (him SSI in Apache, you jsp:include) to pull in static HTML files.

His Apache set-up could have a static wrapper, with a hard-coded version of you JSP code. He'd then be editing snippets of HTML in their own files that could be used as is.

This is a compromise though. As ProDigitalSon mentioned, it would be best to get him used to working with JSPs. Any front-end dev worth his salt shouldn't have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that this person is not working with the team. Rather, he's creating work for them... and it goes both ways. Read on.

I both do and manage front end development. If this UI person was on my team, I would force him to set up a Tomcat server. He just needs to learn some things.

In effect, when implemented properly, JSP is not much different from any other server-side markup language for views, such as Rails + ERB, PHP, .NET etc... even Javascript templating engines (mustache, handlebars, etc.). The same condition checks, for-loops, auth checks - all basic view-layer logic that is needed is available and usable.

If he's on a Java project / team, he needs to learn the Java front-end. It's that simple.

His main tasks should be basic, and frankly, he shouldn't even need to install a Java IDE to do them. They are:

1. Get/push source code + analyze diffs (any source control client)
2. Build / deploy latest to his local environment (scripts or .bat files)
3. Work on the running app*

(*) The last part is where things get tricky. If you work directly on the running server and then accidentally run a fresh deploy before copying over your updates, you're screwed. If you use symlinks (which are also available in Windows), there may be files that only appear post-compilation, or locks, or sync issues when getting latest code - all creating problems.

The way I have found that works best is to work on the code repo location (pre-build), and create two scripts:

1. Build+deploy - stops running server, blows out directories and caches, builds latest, and redploys
2. Update - Synchronizes the View files and any other necessary directories with the deployment target. You must be sure to disable hot-deploy in the Tomcat config, or you'll get memory leak errors.

---

That said, and it should be obvious by now: Java is one of the most difficult ecosystems to develop UI's for. The compiled nature and complex environment requirements make development slow and tedious, with significant dependencies on different people or systems to make a decent product.

JSP itself, while capable as described above, is almost always organized badly, with various ways of includes, tagfiles, partials, frameworks - it becomes a UI person's worst nightmare. GSP (from Grails) solves a lot of the organizational issues, but will require flexibility from the dev team. Even then it is not an "ideal" solution.

JSP syntax - JSTL, C:tags, etc. creates even greater headaches. Front-end people who do not program, don't use IDE's and therefore don't have a way of looking up methods, objects, parameters etc. when writing or customizing conditional logic or loops. The dev team can help by pre-writing these out on the page, but any time there are changes or enhancements needed, it requires meetings, conversations, and compromise.

In the long run, you should abstract the Java app from a separate, more flexible, more capable front-end technology stack, using REST / JSON-based services to talk between the two. (Side note: For performance / apps with scale, ensure you are using either a custom protocol or Web Sockets).

My preference is node.js, because front-end developers can stick with the language they will know best: Javascript / JSON. But it could be anything that your particular front-enders are comfortable with and can do design with.

The key is to eliminate bottlenecks on both front-end and back end. Both tracks should be able to develop and iterate quickly, with the RESTFUL API being the key point of collaboration.

Lastly, for those of you who are aspiring front-end developers / designers but only know Java (or some other server-side technology), I CHALLENGE YOU to learn something new. User-facing technologies are in a constant state of change, and more recently that change has accelerated. If you want to have UI-competitive products, you need to invest in technologies that will make them competitive.